# How do I fix Unicode Display Issue in Windows 7 with either FontTools Font-Merging or Manually Editing a System File?

Tags: python, unicode, fonts, windows-7, emoji

**Update: This issue is now solved. It actually appears that the issue is that the Unicode characters are somehow not being recognized by Uniscribe at all, and so no fallback font is used at all. The only feasible system-wide solution without trying to repair or change Uniscribe appears to be to change the name of Segoe UI Symbol to Arial (this can be done by converting the file to [.ttx XML format](http://www.fontgeek.net/blog/?p=343) and manually editing the file, then converting back to .ttf), and use this new "Arial" font as the base font which other Unicode fonts can be merged into with FontTools. I discuss what I've learned about `merge` / `pyftmerge` in more detail [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1657357/how-do-i-merge-two-fonts-using-fonttools).**

The issue I'm trying to solve is the exact same issue/question asked here many years ago:
https://superuser.com/questions/784078/some-unicode-fonts-not-working-in-windows-7-firefox

If you read through the question/responses, you'll see that no actual conclusion was reached and no actual answer was found as to why some Windows 7 systems fail to display characters in uncommon Unicode blocks like Egyptian Hieroglyphics **even though the relevant fonts are installed**.

Furthermore, no general solution was found either (the OP concluded with a "solution" specifically for Firefox). The OP mentions that he has **very** extensively tried a large number of potential solutions to no avail.

My intuition is that this issue has nothing to do with graphics cards. I believe this is entirely a Windows issue and specifically a Uniscribe issue.

I suspect that the discrepancy between the OP testing the issue on his VM (where the unicode characters display properly) and on his local machine (where the unicode characters do not display), is possibly due to his local machine and his VM having different versions of `usp10.dll`. However, as the question is 6 years old and the OP does not appear to be active, there is no way to ask to confirm this hypothesis.

Upon inspecting `usp10.dll` with a hex editor, there are actually a decent amount of intelligible ASCII sections: [image: usp10.dll]

**My actual question is what "should" I do to solve this issue? And furthermore, if someone has a decent idea of how to actually execute one of the solutions that I'll propose below, please explain the nitty-gritty.** (I don't consider "upgrade to Windows 10" a valid answer. Although I understand that there are many good reasons to do so, please do not post a reply if this is your only suggestion.)

From what I've gathered, I can see 3 solutions to this issue:

1. I can go out of my way to get a VM and a fresh installation of Windows 7 to test my hypothesis relating to `usp10.dll`. If my hypothesis was true, I can *possibly* transfer the "good" version of `usp10.dll` to my local machine. The downside is that I do actually have to go out of my way to do this, as I don't own a VM and I no longer have my Windows 7 installation disc.
2. I can experiment with manually editing `usp10.dll` locally and see if this produces any helpful results. For instance, there may be some parts of the code where I can append additional font names such as `Symbola` and `Aegyptus`. If I'm very lucky, this may fix the issue by allowing Windows to fallback to these fonts. The obvious downside is that I don't understand Uniscribe or Windows DLLs near enough to be "qualified" to do this. Furthermore, I would have to do this for every additional "obscure" unicode font that I install in the future.
3. **Lastly, perhaps the easiest solution I can think of**, is to use the same approach `EmojiOneColor` and `TwitterColorEmoji` uses for their Windows installation procedure. Which is to merge additional fonts (in my case, `Symbola` and `Aegyptus`) into `Segoe UI Symbol`, and I believe this should almost guarantee that these additional Unicode characters are displayed properly, since `Segoe UI Symbol` is used by Windows by default.

The obvious advantage to the last approach is that it's relatively easy to do and almost guaranteed to work. And if defined to not replace any existing glyphs, would also give the same appearance as Windows using the correct fallback font. Furthermore, it can be automated with a script that you can run every time you want to merge a new font into `Segoe UI Symbol`. I currently don't have such a script, but maybe someone here can help me with that ([`TwitterColorEmoji`](https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font/blob/master/windows/install.cmd) uses Python `FontTools`). The downside to this approach is that I believe font files have a max number of glyphs, so there might be a limit to how many fonts I can stack up inside of `Segoe UI Symbol`.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions at [How to change / configure font fallback?](https://superuser.com/q/396160/2366)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try and see if adding a new multi-string value for `Segoe UI Symbol` and appending the additional fonts to it allows the characters to be displayed. Or maybe adding a new value for every single additional font. I don't quite understand how Font Linking works.

Comment: I found this link related to font linking in a different question https://web.archive.org/web/20160516075653/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688134.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, font linking via editing registry did not work. I've tried adding a new multi-string value Segoe UI Symbol (with additional font as value), adding additional font to Tahoma, adding a new multi-string value Arial (with additional font as value), adding a new multi-string value Aegyptus (with and without itself as value), adding font as value to Segoe UI. I've made sure to relogout/login to Windows as indicated by that webpage I linked. And I've also restarted my machine just to be sure.

Comment: If someone knows the "correct" command-line/script way to merge an OpenType font with Segoe UI Symbol or vice versa (without replacing any already-existing Glyphs in Segoe UI Symbol or messing-with/resizing any glyphs) using FontTools. I'm fairly sure it will work as a solution.